# Difference between CMI publish and core Service publish method?

Tags: 2011, core-service

The same component, if I use Content Manager Explorer to publish it, its "Publish Status" changed. But if I use the Core Service to publish it, its "Publish Status" does not change.

```
RenderInstructionData render = new RenderInstructionData { 
    RenderMode = RenderMode.Publish 
};
ResolveInstructionData rid = new ResolveInstructionData { 
    IncludeChildPublications = false 
};
PublishInstructionData pid = new PublishInstructionData { 
    DeployAt = DateTime.Now, 
    MaximumNumberOfRenderFailures = 0, 
    ResolveInstruction = rid, 
    RenderInstruction = render 
};
_client.Publish(
    new String[] { id }, 
    pid, 
    targets.ToArray(), 
    PublishPriority.Low, 
    new ReadOptions()
);
```

*Id is The Component ID*

I really do not understand why the GUI and my code are showing different behavior. Are there any differences between these two ways?

Comment: OK. I've cleaned up your code a bit, to make is easier for people to read. You might want to have a look at the source, to see how to accomplish this (back ticks are for **inline** code snippets) I'll delete my comments in a few minutes, so that they don't distract from your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5383/coreapi-coreservice2010client-publish-method-and-unpublish-method

Comment: Post your resolve instruction

Comment: Mostly you are publishing to wrong target and trying to look at your expected target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various possibilities. Firstly, how are you determining that the behaviour is different? The GUI won't automatically update to reflect changes caused by core service calls.

Another thing that can catch you out is that the context of your publish might be different. In your core service code, you should check that the id you are using for the component represents the component in the correct publication... i.e. one which is configured to allow publishing to your chosen target. If you use the id of the component in the publication where it is stored, this will typically result in the symptoms you describe.

Assuming that the behaviour is actually different, you should be looking at the systems that are running each of these tasks, and how they are configured. It's very common to have a publisher that runs on a completely separate server, where the configuration can be completely different. So - for example, you might have a custom resolver, and it's only available/configured on one server. (Of course, then you'd be looking for reasons why a core service publish would consistently be processed by one server rather than another.)